# What is the difference between a Gradle configuration dependency and a Gradle configuration incoming dependency?

Tags: gradle

Gradle configurations have two properties known as [`dependencies`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:dependencies) and [`incoming`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:incoming). Based on my understanding, we can add a dependency to a configuration through a Gradle dependency block like the following:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

I expect that after the above block of code is executed, `testCompile.dependencies` will return a collection containing at least 1 object representing the JUnit dependency.

I am unsure what `testCompile.incoming` will represent, however.

What is the relationship between a configuration's `dependencies` and `incoming` properties? What is an example of using the incoming property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out with some experimentation. I started by creating a dummy project using Gradle. I have the following Gradle script to try out different properties of the `testCompile` configuration's properties.

```
group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task("dummyFileGenerator") {
    outputs.file '/tmp'
}

// configurations.testCompile.transitive false

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile files('/tmp')

}

println "Printing dependencies"
configurations.testCompile.dependencies.all {
    println(it)
}
println "======="

println "Printing all dependencies"
configurations.testCompile.allDependencies.all {
    println it
}
println '======='

println "printing incoming dependencies"
configurations.testCompile.incoming.dependencies.all {
    println(it)
}
println "======="

println "printing files of incoming dependencies"
configurations.testCompile.incoming.files.forEach {
    println it
}
println "======="

println "printing artifacts of incoming dependencies"
configurations.testCompile.incoming.artifacts.forEach {
    println it
}
println "======="

println "printing files of incoming dependencies (again)"
configurations.testCompile.incoming.files.forEach {
    println it
}
println "======="

task("blecgh") {
    doLast {
        println "Hello!"
    }
}
```

A sample output from this script is:

```
Printing dependencies
DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='junit', name='junit', version='4.12', configuration='default'}
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultSelfResolvingDependency_Decorated@433edba9
=======
Printing all dependencies
DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='junit', name='junit', version='4.12', configuration='default'}
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultSelfResolvingDependency_Decorated@433edba9
=======
printing incoming dependencies
DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='junit', name='junit', version='4.12', configuration='default'}
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultSelfResolvingDependency_Decorated@433edba9
=======
printing files of incoming dependencies
/tmp
/usr/local/google/home/afwang/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec/junit-4.12.jar
/usr/local/google/home/afwang/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
=======
printing artifacts of incoming dependencies
tmp
junit.jar (junit:junit:4.12)
hamcrest-core.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3)
=======
printing files of incoming dependencies (again)
/tmp
/usr/local/google/home/afwang/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec/junit-4.12.jar
/usr/local/google/home/afwang/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
=======
:blecgh
Hello!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.621 secs
```

Interesting bits to note are that `incoming.files` and `incoming.artifacts` contain a representation for the Hamcrest dependency. This suggests that a configuration's `incoming` property includes the artifacts of the configuration's transitive dependencies in addition to the artifacts of the configuration's direct dependencies. This seems to be related to the configuration's `transitive` property. If the `transitive` property is set to false, the `incoming` property will not include the configuration's transitive dependencies' artifacts; only the direct dependencies' artifacts will be contained.

Note that the configuration's `allDependencies` property does not include transitive dependencies. Instead, the `allDependencies` property includes inherited dependencies from the super configuration.

Here's a graph to help explain what I believe these configuration properties represent:

```
configParent -- depParent
|
|
configChild -- depA
            \- depB -- depB1 -- depB2
```

`configParent` and `configChild` are configurations. `configParent` has a direct dependency on `depParent`. `configParent` is the super configuration for `configChild`. `configChild` has direct dependencies `depA` and `depB`. `depB` has a dependency on `depB1`, and `depB1` has a dependency on `depB2`.

`configChild.dependencies` will contain only `depA` and `depB`. `configChild.allDependencies` will contain only `depParent`, `depA`, and `depB`. `configChild.incoming.artifacts` will contain the artifacts of dependencies `depParent`, `depA`, `depB`, `depB1`, and `depB2`. Similarly, `configChild.incoming.files` will contain the files of dependencies `depParent`, `depA`, `depB`, `depB1`, and `depB2`.

I'd summarize by saying that a configuration's incoming property is the resolution of all of its dependencies, including inherited dependencies form super configurations.